# return span's null value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get span value inside flike div, when i click on 'A' tag. In my script, I get 'null' value. Where is my fault? Thank you.

my html code:

```
<div class="bottom"><div class="like">
    <a><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>5</span></a>
    <div class="flike"><span>5</span></div>
</div></div>
```

my script:

```
$(function () {
    $('.like a').on('click', function () {
        var svalue = $(this).next(".flike span").html();
        alert(svalue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong selector to target span element. You need to first find next div element and then find span element in it.using space selector to target in element will not work in dom traversing methods like `.next()`,`.prev()`,`.siblings()`,etc.  use:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.like a').on('click', function () {
        var svalue = $(this).next(".flike").find('span').html();
        alert(svalue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom"><div class="like">
    <a><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>5</span></a>
    <div class="flike"><span>5</span></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Your code is correct now, but the explanation doesn't really match it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to find next element ('flike') and then span -

```js
$(function () {
    $('.like a').on('click', function () {
        var svalue = $(this).next(".flike").find('span').html();
        alert(svalue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom"><div class="like">
    <a><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>5</span></a>
    <div class="flike"><span>5</span></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
    $('.like a').on('click', function () {
        var svalue = $('.flike').children('span').text();
        alert(svalue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom"><div class="like">
    <a><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>5</span></a>
    <div class="flike"><span>5</span></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can get the value of that element as follows:

var spanVal = $(".flike span").text();

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use it direct

```js
$(function () {
    $('.like a span').on('click', function () {
        var svalue = $(this).html();
        alert(svalue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom"><div class="like">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>5</span></a>
    <div class="flike"><span>5</span></div>
</div></div>
```